# Filtro en registros con Laravel 5.4.*

Tags: laravel

Buenas, quisiera saber que pudiera herramienta o método se pudiera utilizar para un filtro dinamico de registro, ejemplo, tengo un archivo llamado `contacts.blade.php` donde muestro una especie de libreta de direcciones, lo que quiero hacer es colocar un mecanismo (Input, Select) que me permita filtrar más rápido los contactos según escoja el usuario, le dejo exactamente el frag de código de lo que mostrare según el filtro:

```
<!-- Contacts -->
@foreach($Contacts as $Contact)
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 profile_details">
          <div class="well profile_view">
               <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h4 class="brief"
                         <i>{{ $Contact->positions }} | 
                            <small>{{ $Contact->depart }}</small></i>
                    </h4>
                     <div class="left col-xs-7">
                          <h2>{{ $Contact->f_name }} {{ $Contact->l_name }}</h2>
                                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                                <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> {{ $Contact->email }}</li>
                                                <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 40-215</li>
                                                <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($Contact->date_bjob)->diffForHumans() }}</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="right col-xs-5 text-center">
                                            <img src="{{ Gravatar::src($Contact->email) }}" alt="" class="img-circle img-responsive">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 bottom text-center">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"> <i class="fa fa-user">
                                            </i> <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> </button>
                                            <a href="{{ route('profile', $Contact->username ) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
                                                <i class="fa fa-user"> </i> Ver Perfil
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @endforeach
                            <!-- ./Contacts -->
```

El Controlador

```
public function index()
{
    Carbon::setLocale('es');
    $Contacts = dk_profile_user::
                select('dk_profile_user.id','dk_profile_user.f_name','dk_profile_user.l_name','users.email','dk_profile_user.address',
                    'dk_profile_user.status','dk_profile_user.image_profile','dk_profile_user.date_bday',
                    'dk_profile_user.date_bjob','dk_master_area.name as depart','dk_area.name as area','dk_profession.name as profession',
                    'dk_positions.name as positions','dk_profile_user.username')
                ->join('dk_area','dk_area.id','=','dk_profile_user.id_area')
                ->join('dk_master_area','dk_master_area.id','=','dk_area.id_master_area')
                ->join('dk_profession','dk_profession.id','=','dk_profile_user.id_profession')
                ->join('dk_positions','dk_positions.id','=','dk_profile_user.id_positions')
                ->join('users','users.id','=','dk_profile_user.id')
                ->get();
    return View('/contacts')->with('Contacts',$Contacts);
}
```

**ACTUALIZO:**

Según la respuesta de @Pablo Contreras, intente adaptarlo a mi proyecto, pero me retorna un error en la consola: `POST http://192.168.21.210:8000/contacts/m/0 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Mi Route:

```
// CONTACTOS
Route::get('contacts','contacts\ContactsController@index');
Route::get('listall/{page?}','contacts\ContactsController@listall');
Route::post('contacts/{field1}/{field2}','ContactsController@listadoContactos');
```

Mi Controller

```
public function listadoContactos(Request $req, $field1, $field2)
{
    if($req->ajax()) {
        $result = dk_profile_user::
                    select('dk_profile_user.id',DB::raw('CONCAT(dk_profile_user.f_name, " ", dk_profile_user.l_name) AS name'),
                        'users.email','dk_profile_user.address','dk_profile_user.status','dk_profile_user.image_profile',
                        'dk_profile_user.date_bday', 'dk_profile_user.date_bjob','dk_master_area.name as depart',
                        'dk_area.name as area','dk_profession.name as profession','dk_positions.name as positions',
                        'dk_profile_user.username')
                    ->join('dk_area','dk_area.id','=','dk_profile_user.id_area')
                    ->join('dk_master_area','dk_master_area.id','=','dk_area.id_master_area')
                    ->join('dk_profession','dk_profession.id','=','dk_profile_user.id_profession')
                    ->join('dk_positions','dk_positions.id','=','dk_profile_user.id_positions')
                    ->join('users','users.id','=','dk_profile_user.id');
                    if($field1!=="") {
                        $result->where('dk_profile_user.name','like','%'.$field1.'%');
                    }
                    if ($field2!==0) {
                        $result->where('dk_profile_user.area','=',$field2);
                    }
                    $results = $result->get();
        return Response::json(array('resultado' => $results));
    }
}
```

Script en mi vista

```
//Para un input type text:
        $('#person').keyup(function(e) {
            Contactos();
        });
        //Para un select:
        $('#departament').on( 'change', function (e) {
            Contactos();
        });
   function Contactos() {
            var field1 = $("#person").val();
            var field2 = $("#departament").val();
            $.post("contacts/"+field1+"/"+field2+"" ,function(response){
                console.log(response.resultado); 
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que utilizas jQuery, y sino es asi [acá tienes el enlace del cdn](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js)

**1.** En la ruta:

```
Route::post('listadoContactos/{field1}/{field2}','Controller@getListadoContactos');
```

**2.** En el controlador:

```
public function getListadoContactos(Request $req, $field1, $field2){
    if($req->ajax()){
        $result = dk_profile_user::
                select('dk_profile_user.id','dk_profile_user.f_name','dk_profile_user.l_name','users.email','dk_profile_user.address',
                    'dk_profile_user.status','dk_profile_user.image_profile','dk_profile_user.date_bday',
                    'dk_profile_user.date_bjob','dk_master_area.name as depart','dk_area.name as area','dk_profession.name as profession',
                    'dk_positions.name as positions','dk_profile_user.username')
                ->join('dk_area','dk_area.id','=','dk_profile_user.id_area')
                ->join('dk_master_area','dk_master_area.id','=','dk_area.id_master_area')
                ->join('dk_profession','dk_profession.id','=','dk_profile_user.id_profession')
                ->join('dk_positions','dk_positions.id','=','dk_profile_user.id_positions')
                ->join('users','users.id','=','dk_profile_user.id')
                ->where('users.id','=',$field1)
                ->where('users.id','=',$field2)
                ->get();
        return Response::json(array('resultado' => $result));
    }
}
```

**3.** En la vista, en el `script`, vas a colocar la función y su llamado en el `ready` (para que se ejecute cuando cargue la ruta).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Contactos();
});

function Contactos() {
    var field1 = $("#field1").val();
    var field2 = $("#field2").val();
    //obtendras los valores de los distintos campos y los enviaras por parametros al controlador.
    //puedes inventarte un array que contenga todos los valores de los campos de la vista y así los envías en un solo parámetro al controlador. No tengo chance para probar así que lo dejo a tu propia experiencia :D
    $.post("listadoContactos/"+field1+"/"+field2+"" ,function(response){
        console.log(response.resultado); //response contiene todo lo que obtienes de la funcion en el controlador
    });
};
```

**4.** Para que se ejecute en cada cambio de estado de cada campo solo debes usar sus diferentes formas:

```
//Para un input type text:
$('#field1').keyup(function(e) {
    Contactos();
});

//Para un select:
$('#field2').on( 'change', function (e) {
    Contactos();
});
```

**NOTA:** no envíes la variable a la vista cuando la hagas con la función del index, de esta manera que te estoy enseñando cargas los resultados del listado del controlador con el filtrado que manejas.

**PD:** sin mas nada que acotar, esta seria la manera de crear el listado de contactos como lo manejas y la manera de filtrarlo.

Saludos, estamos para ayudarnos entre todos :D

Comment: No es la clase de filtro que necesito, debido a que solo funciona si usas tablas (supongo), en este caso, no uso tabla, si no lo [lo que ves aquí](http://imgur.com/mm0R7Qq)

Comment: Entonces en el ready de javascript llama a una funcion en el controlador, que por esa lista le pases parametros a una consulta con where. Cada vez que realices un state change en alguno de los input o select vuelva a llamar los resultados de esa funcion. No se si me explico bien.

Comment: ¿En parte, como haría exactamente esto: _en el ready de javascript *llama a una función en el controlador*_?

Comment: en unas 6 horas puedo colocarte exactamente lo que necesitas por que ahorita voy saliendo. Si nadie ha podido te doy un solución.

Comment: @MaykolRivas Listo, modificado, intenta de esta manera, creo que es lo que necesitas :D

Comment: Actualice la pregunta, según tu respuesta. me retorna un error en la ruta

Comment: @MaykolRivas ok, agrega la funcion "Contactos()" por favor :D

Comment: Listo @Pablo, ahi edite de nuevo la pregunta

Comment: Para el caso `/contact/m/0` **m** seria todas las personas que tengan **M** en el campo del nombre y **0** el departamento al que pertenecen, siendo **0** seria algo como **all**..

Comment: Ya me iba a volver loco del por que no te reconoce la ruta, pues la estas indicando mal en el $.post, nota que dice "contact" y en la ruta dice "contacts"

Comment: Cometi un error en la ruta de la funcion _Contact_, ya que dice `/contact/m/0` cuando deberia ser `/contacts/m/0`, acomodando esto el error me cambia a `POST http://192.168.21.210:8000/contacts/m/0 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: ¿Utilizas Chrome?

Comment: Si @Pablo, uso Chrome. ¿Eso afectaría en algo?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55087/discussion-between-pablo-contreras-and-maykol-rivas).

Comment: @MaykolRivas volvi.. llegate al chat..

Answer (score 1):

@PabloContreras Gracias por tu respuesta, pude dar con una solucion cambiando un par de cosas para que me pudieran funcionar.

**1. En la ruta:**

**Antes:**

```
Route::post('listadoContactos/{field1}/{field2}','Controller@getListadoContactos');
```

**Despues:**

```
Route::get('contacts/{field1}/{field2}','contacts\ContactsController@listadoContactos');
```

**2. En el controlador:**

**Antes:**

```
public function getListadoContactos(Request $req, $field1, $field2){
 if($req->ajax()){
    $result = dk_profile_user::
            select('dk_profile_user.id','dk_profile_user.f_name','dk_profile_user.l_name','users.email','dk_profile_user.address',
                'dk_profile_user.status','dk_profile_user.image_profile','dk_profile_user.date_bday',
                'dk_profile_user.date_bjob','dk_master_area.name as depart','dk_area.name as area','dk_profession.name as profession',
                'dk_positions.name as positions','dk_profile_user.username')
            ->join('dk_area','dk_area.id','=','dk_profile_user.id_area')
            ->join('dk_master_area','dk_master_area.id','=','dk_area.id_master_area')
            ->join('dk_profession','dk_profession.id','=','dk_profile_user.id_profession')
            ->join('dk_positions','dk_positions.id','=','dk_profile_user.id_positions')
            ->join('users','users.id','=','dk_profile_user.id')
            ->where('users.id','=',$field1)
            ->where('users.id','=',$field2)
            ->get();
    return Response::json(array('resultado' => $result));
 }
}
```

**Despues:**

```
public function listadoContactos(Request $req, $field1, $field2)
{
    if($req->ajax()) {
        $result = dk_profile_user::
                    select('dk_profile_user.id','dk_profile_user.f_name', 'dk_profile_user.l_name',
                        'users.email','dk_profile_user.address','dk_profile_user.status','dk_profile_user.image_profile',
                        'dk_profile_user.date_bday', 'dk_profile_user.date_bjob','dk_master_area.name as depart',
                        'dk_area.name as area','dk_profession.name as profession','dk_positions.name as positions',
                        'dk_profile_user.username')
                    ->join('dk_area','dk_area.id','=','dk_profile_user.id_area')
                    ->join('dk_master_area','dk_master_area.id','=','dk_area.id_master_area')
                    ->join('dk_profession','dk_profession.id','=','dk_profile_user.id_profession')
                    ->join('dk_positions','dk_positions.id','=','dk_profile_user.id_positions')
                    ->join('users','users.id','=','dk_profile_user.id');
                    if($field1!=="") {
                        $result->where('dk_profile_user.f_name','like','%'.$field1.'%');
                        $result->orWhere('dk_profile_user.l_name','like','%'.$field1.'%');
                    }
                    if ($field2!=='0') {
                        $result->where('dk_profile_user.area','=',$field2);
                    }
                    $results = $result->get();
        return \Response::json(array('resultado' => $results));
    }
}
```

**3. En la vista, en el script.**

**Antes:**

```
function Contactos() {
     var field1 = $("#field1").val();
     var field2 = $("#field2").val();
    $.post("listadoContactos/"+field1+"/"+field2+"" ,function(response){
    console.log(response.resultado); 
     });
};
```

**Después:**

```
function Contactos() {
            var field1 = $("#person").val();
            var field2 = $("#departament").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'contacts/' + field1 +'/'+ field2,
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response.resultado); 
                }
            });
        }
```

**4. Para que se ejecute en cada cambio de estado de cada campo solo debes usar sus diferentes formas:**

**Esta si quedo igual:**

```
//Para un input type text:
$('#field1').keyup(function(e) {
    Contactos();
});
//Para un select:
$('#field2').on( 'change', function (e) {
    Contactos();
});
```

Muchas Gracias, aunque se hicieron algunos cambios pequeños, la lógica de la respuesta me ayuda mucho a dar con una solución que funcionara correctamente en mi proyecto.