# ¿Cómo hacer un filtro a través de listas desplegables en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un sistema que debe dar de alta "Plantas", esa planta pertenece a un Estado. Lo que necesito hacer es listar todos los países en una lista desplegable y dependiendo lo que se seleccione cargar y mostrar en otra lista desplegable los estados del país seleccionado.

Esto es algo que he hecho varias veces en PHP normal pero nunca en Laravel (es mi primer proyecto con este Framework).

El código que tengo es el siguiente en el controlador de Planta:

```
public function create()
    {
            $countries = Country::all();
            return view('plants.create', compact('countries'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $fields = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required|unique:user_types|max:60|min:2',
            'state_id' =>  'exists:states,id',    
            'city' =>  'required|max:60|min:2',    
            'address' =>  'max:500',    
        ]);
            Plant::create($fields);
            return "Plant created";

    }
```

Desconozco donde debo cargar y mandar los estados una vez seleccionado el país. ¿Debo mandar todo y que JS se encargue?.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar al controlador una busqueda por ejemplo:

```
public function getArteComida()

{

    $arte = Negocios->galeria()->where('categoria', '=', 'comida')->get();
    return View::make('gastronomia.arte', compact('arte'));

}
```

Y lo llamas a tu lista desplegable.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: También actualmente se encuentra un hilo ya creado que puede ayudarte [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53972/filtro-en-registros-con-laravel-5-4?rq=1)